# How to save the output of php variables used in inline css code to the main style.css?

Tags: php, css

I have some PHP variables that each represent some user settings set via a theme options interface such as:

- theme colors
- typography
- etc.

All these variables are in a file called `dynamic-style.php`:

```
<?php
<style type="text/css">
body {
    color: <?php echo $text_color; ?>;
}
</style>
?>
```

Is there a way to get the parsed CSS code from `dynamic-style.php` and save it to the main `style.css` at the bottom of the file? I need this to be done to decrease the number of HTTP requests on a public theme.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php), specifically [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) will point you in the right direction.  My suggestion is to write the name/value pairs to an array, insert a comment at the top of a blank CSS file and add an import directive to the master style sheet until you test the output, then dump the array into the test stylesheet.

Comment: @E Carter Young thanks but I do not think it is a good idea to use `file_put_contents` in a theme development since the theme check plugin output some warnings regarding to it. Also if I'm not mistaken, some servers do not allow `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: If it isn't allowed, even for testing, use the [PHPFile Methods](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/files.php) instead.  Read From Files to Upload in the tutorial for all the functions.  These are [Manual: Wrapper Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) for the function I gave you.  If these are acceptable I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the answer you're looking for, as it does not add styles directly to the main stylesheet, but the way this would typically be handled is with the `wp_add_inline_style()` function. It would use your primary stylesheet (or whichever enqueued stylesheet you define) as a dependency, but would print the styles inline in the `<head>` (rather than in the stylesheet itself), so it at least isn't a call to an additional stylesheet file.